# How can i integrate stripe recurring in react and express with custom checkout page?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, subscription

I am working on a project where I have to integrate **Stripe Recurring Payment** with custom checkout page.

I tried many ways but nothing is working.

I hope i get a answer here.

Also Please someone help me with how to **store payments every month in data base**.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have recurring payments with Express and React using Stripe. At a high level you need to:

1. Create a [product and a recurring price](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/products-prices), either with the dashboard or with the API
2. Create a Subscription on the backend and retrieve the `latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` of the subscription. You can see  an example [here with Express](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription).
3. Use the client secret to collect payment information on the frontend. For React this is covered on [this documentation page](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react).

To store the monthly payments in your database, you can use [Stripe webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to listen to the [`invoice.paid`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) event